# Issue compiling with a new module on Linux

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I'm trying to compile a project that contains different modules (`.h` files) so I'm using a `makefile`. I added a new module called `semaphore_v2.h` which I included in another module called `connection.h`. `connection.h` is included into `jack.c` where the main process is. When compiling using `make` command, I get the following error:

[image]

Seems like despite I included the module, it doesn't keep track of the references of the `semaphore_v2.h` module and I can't find the issue here. What's wrong?

**makefile**:

```
all: compilation

jack.o: jack.c
    gcc -c jack.c -Wall -Wextra
semaphore_v2.o: semaphore_v2.c semaphore_v2.h
    gcc -c semaphore_v2.c -Wall -Wextra
files.o: files.c files.h
    gcc -c files.c -Wall -Wextra
connection.o: connection.c connection.h
    gcc -c connection.c -Wall -Wextra
compilation: jack.o files.o connection.o
    gcc jack.o connection.o files.o -o jack -Wall -Wextra -lpthread
```

**connection.h**

```
#ifndef _CONNECTION_H_
#define _CONNECTION_H_

#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "files.h"

#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#include "semaphore_v2.h"

typedef struct {
    int socketfd;
    int memid;
    semaphore *sinc;
}thread_input;

...
```

**jack.c**

```
#include <signal.h>
#include "connection.h"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your makefile `compilation` target to include also semaphore_v2.o

so you should have such a line at your makefile:

```
compilation: jack.o files.o connection.o semaphore_v2.o

    gcc jack.o connection.o files.o semaphore_v2.o -o jack -Wall -Wextra -lpthread
```

Note semaphore_v2.o appears twice, one time as a dependency to this target and one time as input to the gcc command.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add that there, thanks. But now I'm getting this error: `gcc-9: error: semaphore_v2.o: No such file or directory`... I think compilation is good and also are the files... any clue?

Comment: Look at my answer, and note you should add semaphore_v2.o twice to the compilation target (one time as dependency and one time as input to the gcc command). I think you added it only once, and this causes the problem you described.